# How do I completely delete user info from git terminal?

Tags: git, github

I created a test git and github account a few days ago. Today I created a new github account and updated my git terminal username and email using **git config --global user.name** and **git config --global user.email** commands. But when I push a repo using **git push origin master** to my new github account, it still appears to use the test git username that I created before and gives me this error:

remote: Permission to *github repo url* denied to *old username*.

fatal: unable to access *github repo url*: The requested URL returned error: 403

I've tried deleting the old user too but nothing works.
When I run **git config --global --list**, it shows my new details.

I've tried a lot of things before posting on here so I really don't know what the problem is. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does `git config --local --list` show?

Comment: Do you use ssh authentication?

Answer (score 6):

```
git credential-osxkeychain erase
host=github.com
protocol=https
[Press Return]
```

Then you can do push, and the terminal is going to answer for new credentials.

From [ikaikastine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35903903/3994630)

Answer (score 3):

I've been struggling with an issue of this kind for 2 hours or so, and finnally picked an idea from one of the answers: it was to clean the config file. To do that, I just opened it on an editor (sudo gedit .git/config) and saved the file totally empty. After that, I filled some of the missed info like user.name, user.email. Then, I've made an *git init* and a *git clone* , and editted one of the files. When I tried to upload it with the *git push origin master* it prompted me to enter the credentials (Username and Password), and finally I was able to submit my changes! I hope it helps you and I'm sorry about my English, it's not my native tongue.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, the only thing that worked for me, is manually remove the git credentials  save in the control panel:
**Control Panel → User Accounts → Credential Manager → Windows Credential Manager → erase the github credentials**.

Although I tried all the other git commands configurations, this deletion, and then re-entering username and email on push, made it connect to the right account.

Answer (score 3):

I also faced this issue so i had removed name and email from config file by using `my_repogit1 shaileshyadaav$ git config --local --unset-all user.name`and after this you can verify details by using `git config --list`

Comment: I did unset local and global then it asks user credentials
git config --global --unset-all user.name

Comment: that worked when you have to reset users from system

Answer (score 1):

**Git documentation says:**

> The first place Git looks for these values is in an /etc/gitconfig file, which contains values for every user on the system and all of their repositories. If you pass the option --system to git config, it reads and writes from this file specifically.
>
> The next place Git looks is the ~/.gitconfig (or ~/.config/git/config) file, which is specific to each user. You can make Git read and write to this file by passing the --global option.
>
> Finally, Git looks for configuration values in the configuration file in the Git directory (.git/config) of whatever repository you’re currently using. These values are specific to that single repository.
>
> **Each of these “levels” (system, global, local) overwrites values in the previous level**, so values in .git/config trump those in /etc/gitconfig, for instance.

So, maybe you could open .git/config with a text editor and check that your user.email and other variables are what you want them to be.

Answer (score -1):

You need to remove the remote url first and add the new one:

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin <url>
```

Comment: This changes only the url of the remote repo.