# Able to edit my repo from an account that I never gave permission

Tags: git, github

I'm unexpectedly able to edit my repo from an account that I never  gave permission.

I have two accounts, **MainAccount** and **SecondAccount**, on GitHub.

I created a repo on **MainAccount** called **my_main_repo**.

On my computer, I was previously logged in as **MainAccount** but I switched it to- **SecondAccount** using these commands.

```sh
git config --global user.email "secondaccount@gmail.com"
git config --global user.name "SecondAccount" 
git config --global user.password "mypassword123"
```

***Update: As phd mentions in the comments, `user.password` is not a config setting and doesn't do anything.*

I cloned the repo, made a change, and pushed to master.

#### Expectation:

Since I never gave **SecondAccount** permission to edit the repo, I expected to get a 403 error like this:

```sh
remote: Permission to MainAccount/my_main_repo.git denied to SecondAccount.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/MainAccount/my_main_repo.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

#### Actual:

Instead, I was able to edit the repo from **SecondAccount** without needing any permission. When I go to the repo, it shows that a commit was made by **SecondAccount**.

Why am I able to edit this repo from an account that I never gave permission to commit?

### Update:

While the git config was set to **SecondAccount**, I tried to push to a remote repo that belongs to **SecondAccount**  but unexpectedly I got a 403 error. In the error it says `remote: Permission to SecondAccount/test.git denied to MainAccount.`. So it still thinks I'm on the main account even though `git config user.name` and `git config user.email` return **SecondAccount** account info.

Comment: `user.name`/`user.email` have nothing with accounts and authorization. And there is no such config setting `user.password`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some conflict. Github still thought I was logged in as **MainAcount**.

To fix it:

```
git credential-osxkeychain erase
host=github.com
protocol=https
[Press Return]
```

The terminal is going to ask for new credentials when you push.

if that doesn't work

```
git config credential.username 'SecondAccount'
```

[original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39334262/how-do-i-completely-delete-user-info-from-git-terminal#answer-45521498)